# User controls communicating via Commands - how?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm working on my first project in WPF/XAML, and there's a lot I've not figured out.

My problem is simple - I need a window that has a bunch of fields at the top, with which the user will enter his selection criteria, a retrieve button, and a data grid.  When the user clicks on the button, a query is run, and the results are used to populate the grid.

Now the simple and obvious and wrong way to implement this is to have a single module containing a single window, and have everything contained within it - entry fields, data grid, the works.  That kind of mangling of responsibilities makes for an unmaintainable mess.

So what I have is a window that is responsible for little more than layout, that contains two user controls - a criteria control that contains the entry fields and the retrieve button, and a data display control that contains the data grid.

The question is how to get the two talking to each other.

Years back, I would have added a function pointer to the criteria control.  The window would have set it to point to a function in the display control, and when the button was clicked, it would have called into the display control, passing the selection criteria.

More recently, I would have added an event to the criteria control.  I would have had the window set a handler in the display control to listen to the event, and when the button was clicked, it would have raised the event.

Both of these mechanisms would work, in WPF. But neither is very XAMLish.  It looks to me like WPF has provided the ICommand interface specifically to accommodate these kinds of connection issues, but I've not yet really figured out how they are intended to work.  And none of the examples I've seen seem to fit my simple scenario.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to fit ICommand to this problem?  Or direct me to a decent explanation online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MVVM is the prevalent pattern used with WPF and Silverlight development. You should have a read up on it.

Essentially, you would have a view model that exposes a command to perform the search. That same view model would also expose properties for each of your criteria fields. The view(s) would then bind to the various properties on the view model:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NameCriteria}"/>

...

<Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}".../>

...

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"/>
```

Where your view model would look something like:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly ICommand searchCommand;
    private string nameCriteria;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.searchCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.OnSearch, this.CanSearch);
    }

    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get { return this.searchCommand; }
    }

    public string NameCriteria
    {
        get { return this.nameCriteria; }
        set
        {
            if (this.nameCriteria != value)
            {
                this.nameCriteria = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.NameCriteria);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSearch()
    {
        // search logic, do in background with BackgroundWorker or TPL, then set Results property when done (omitted for brevity)
    }

    private bool CanSearch()
    {
        // whatever pre-conditions to searching you want here
        return !string.IsEmpty(this.NameCriteria);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using view models.  I didn't mention it because that's not where the problem lies.  I can define a method in the display control's view model, and expose a command that executes it.  Binding that to a UI element in the display control's view would be simple. But that's not my problem. I need to trigger the command from a UI control that doesn't have - and shouldn't have - access to the display control's view model.

Comment: @Jeff: in that case, just use an event aggregator, which allows decoupled components to collaborate. Prism has one, or you could grab one from elsewhere or write your own.

Comment: That seems like serious overkill for a problem as constrained as two controls in the same window talking to each other.

Comment: Which is exactly why my original answer suggested a shared view model. You could set up a relationship between view models too, but IMO you're better off just using an event aggregator at that point unless the relationship is very well defined (eg. parent-child).